# data coming from wrong variable - CSV

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm writing a beatifulsoup webcrawler.  The script gets the correct data and writes it to a file in csv format.  However, when attempting to read the data back (near the end of the code) I open the file again using different variable names and try to read.  However, the output of the last print line is a pile of HTML code from the original site.  I assume it's from the 'soup' string.  What is going on?

```
import datetime
import csv
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


file_name = "/users/ripple/Dropbox/Python/FinViz.txt"
file = open(file_name,"w")

url = "http://www.finviz.com"
print 'Grabbing from: ' + url + '...\n'
try:
        r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
except urllib2.URLError as e:
           r = e
if r.code in (200, 401):    
    #get the table data from the page
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    #send to beautiful soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    i=1
    for table in soup("table", { "class" : "t-home-table"}):
        #First and second tables
        if i==1 or i==2:
            for tr in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
                if i<3:
                    col = tr.findAll('td')
                    ticker = col[0].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
                    price = col[1].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
                    change = col[2].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
                    volume = col[3].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
                    metric = col[5].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
                    record = ticker + ',' + price + ',' + change + ',' + volume + ',' + metric + '\n'
                    print record
                    file.write(record)
        if i==3:
            file.write('END\n')
        # Third and fourth tables
        if i==3 or i==4:
            for tr in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:  
                    col = tr.findAll('td')
                    ticker1 = col[0].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
                    ticker2 = col[1].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
                    ticker3 = col[2].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
                    ticker4 = col[3].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
                    metric = col[5].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore')
                    record = ticker1 + ',' + ticker2 + ',' + ticker3 + ',' + ticker4 + ',' + metric + '\n'
                    print record
                    file.write(record)
        i+=1
#if the page does not open
else: 
    print "ERROR:"
file.close()
#open written file to read tickers and download tables from finviz
file = open(file_name,"r")
finviz_csv = csv.reader(file)
for row in finviz_csv:
    stock = col[0]
    print stock
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question rather quickly.  It should look like this:

```
for row in finviz_csv:
    colnum = 1
    for col in row:
        if colnum==1:
            stock = col
            print col
```